# Ways to destroy a casters arcane focus

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, spell-components

I want too make a character explicitly too shut down mages  and was curious what methods of destroying an arcane focus or component pouch exist. Getting the item away would also work. Unfortunately effects like shatter dont work on held items, is there a spell that would work for this or an item?

Comment: What makes assassination in bed not viable?

Comment: @trish what do you mean?

Comment: Why would you need special magic if you can just shut down all the mages by sneaking into their towers and murdering them in their sleep?

Comment: Because you can get in coment with them, and "just kill them In there sleep" could be a awnser too basicly any enemy